# How can I drag the start screen (instead of scrolling)?

Tags: windows-8, mouse, start-screen

I have many tiles on my start screen, which gives my start screen a scrollbar at the bottom.

My mouse has a problem with the scroll wheel so that I can't scroll where I want. Because it is a great mouse (despite that problem) I don't want to change my mouse.

Is there any way to make the start screen draggable?

Comment: keep moving the mouse over to the right even when its still on the egde of the screen I call it slam it into the side

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although I don't have idea about how to make the start screen draggable, I can suggest you several other options...

1. Use Left & Right arrow keys
2. Use (-) icon on bottom right to navigate faster
3. Click on scroll bare it-self

Moreover I suggest to remove unnecessary tiles from start screen.

Comment: You can also use your num keys (4 and 6) when Num Lock is off.

Answer (score 0):

If you drag your mouse out of the right screen edge, the screen will move.